# How to run Fastlane action in a subfolder

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm using [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/)to build my iOS project and I'm using the [Carthage](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Actions.md#carthage) action

The problem is that I have several iOS projects in different subfolders so I need to run the `carthage(command: "bootstrap")` in that subfolder.

I tried changing to the directory where the project is but it does not work

```
lane :test do
    Dir.chdir("../MyProject") do
        carthage(command: "update")
    end
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

I ended up just calling a script in the subfolder:

```
lane :build do
    Dir.chdir("../MySubdir") do
        sh "carthage bootstrap --platform iOS"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem having several similar projects and trying to reuso `Fastfile` for all for of them.

My approach was to have a generic `Fastfile` on the root `MyProject/fastlane` folder with all logic needed, like your

```
lane :test do
  carthage(command: "update")
end
```

Then, for each project/subfolders you have a Fastfile that only [loads the main `Fastfile` from your `../MyProject` folder](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Advanced.md#importing-another-fastfile), like:

```
import "../MyProject/fastlane/Fastfile"
```

After that you can execute commands on specific folders having a shared logic for all projects, being able to fox issues and increment the commands only in one place with also the ability to customize for each project using the [override_lane command](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Advanced.md#note)

Comment: do yo uknow if you can do this with import_from_git as well ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt I believe it does. I have tested on early 2.x versions of Fastlane and it did work at the time, I suggest testing on newer ones to make sure it still does